# java code to popup file chooser in client machine

Tags: java, zk, adempiere

I was trying to pop up a file chooser on a process that run client side (web). But the file chooser window comes on the server machine.

Here we just use JFileChooser...

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogTitle("Save Log File as"); 
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("AttendenceBug.html"));
```

the work is based on adempiere erp that uses zk framework.

Comment: Try to ask in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please share your efforts

Comment: don't put comments, you can update your question.

Comment: @junsid Please use the edit facility to edit your post with enhancements...

Comment: Did I understand correctly? You are trying to use JFileChooser on some webapp's server side code to show the dialog to the user of that webapp?

Comment: yes. want popup the file chooser in client side to save a file.

Comment: and what about the Zk's fileupload component?

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogTitle("Save Log File as"); 
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("AttendenceBug.html"));
```

In *Adempiere* there are two possible *Clients* a user might use.

The local **Swing** based clients run on the user's PC, in this case the client PC does nearly all the work outside of Accounting & Workflow.  This is the traditional **Fat client-server** architecture most popular in the 90s.

The second, webUI, uses the **zk Framework** which in turn is based on Ajax.  When the user uses this interface, all code is running on *Server* and the *Client* (PC) is only handling in the (web) UI elements. In fact with zk Framework the server processes most of the UI too so the user's PC is only rendering the resulting html.

The **JfileChooser** from your example code is a Swing component, it knows nothing about the web (or Server) and when runs, as you experienced, it opens the selection on the system on which it runs – the *Server* in this case.

There is an example of file selector in base Adempiere.
The Import file loader which you can find at

```
System Admin->Data->Data Import->Import File Loader
```

Click on the button labels

The code that manages this is in zk webui is

```
org.adempiere.webui.apps.form.WfileImport.java
```

In its initialization method **jbInit()** it creates the button

```
bFile.setLabel(Msg.getMsg(Env.getCtx(), "FileImportFile"));
bFile.setTooltiptext(Msg.getMsg(Env.getCtx(), "FileImportFileInfo"));
bFile.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, this);
```

which, when clicked executes

```
        if (e.getTarget() == bFile)
        {
            cmd_loadFile();
            invalidate();
        }

the cmd_loadFile method is doing the work
private void cmd_loadFile()
    {
        Media media = null;

        try 
        {
            media = Fileupload.get();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (media == null)
            return;

        if (media.isBinary()) {
            m_file_istream = media.getStreamData();
        }
        else {
            ListItem listitem = fCharset.getSelectedItem();
            if (listitem == null) {
                m_file_istream = new ReaderInputStream(media.getReaderData());
            } else {
                Charset charset = (Charset)listitem.getValue();
                m_file_istream = new ReaderInputStream(media.getReaderData(), charset.name());
            }
        }

        log.config(media.getName());
        bFile.setLabel(media.getName());

        cmd_reloadFile();
    }
```

This uses a zk Framework component **Fileupload** to actually open the file selection dialog you want and selects the file to load.  The rest of the method then loads the selected file.

From your sample code, it appears once the file is selected you want to save the file. Since the file is saved on the server you really want to upload a file to the server! This is just a slight variation of the above and the zk website provides some example code to achieve this.

```
public class Upload {

    public static void saveToDisk() throws Exception {
        org.zkoss.util.media.Media media = Fileupload.get();

        File f=new File(media.getName());
        InputStream inputStream= media.getStreamData();
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
        out.write(buf,0,len);
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();

        String filepath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        mdbConverter mdb = new mdbConverter();

        Messagebox.show(filepath);
        }
}
```

[source](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/43545/how-to-save-uploaded-file-on-right-place/)

By merging the two examples you should be able to create a new enhancement to Adempiere to complete your task.